# Magento2 - How to execute validator on form

Tags: magento2, form-validation

I've extended the register form with some AJAX functionality and added a custom validator method decribed [here](http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-add-new-custom-form-validation/). Now I want to execute the validation process after getting the result of the AJAX call.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

if You're trying to validate the form, follow the @Mage2.PRO answer. But as you mentioned in your comment that you're using a source to validate one field using ajax, then, you can use `$.validator.validateElement($("#yourElement"));` 
this'll show the error message as it'd when submitting a form.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The forms are automatically validated before its submission.
You can also run a form validation manually.
You should load the `mage/validation` library and then call `$(form).validation()`.

Comment: Yes I know. I want to execute the validation for only the AJAX Input field, if the result is false. In Magento 1 I could use  `Validation.validate($(FIELD_NAME))`

Comment: @ClassMP please mention that in your question.